# Image Name in HTML File Object

Tags: php, html

Image of File Object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSNoD.jpg

HTML of File Object:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

I want to receive the name of the image that i search in file object. In that image i want to receive Practidose.fw.png

I try to do this:

```
$imagem = mysql_escape_string($_POST['file']['name']);
```

I try this too and its not working:

```
$imagem = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

And i receive this error:

Illegal string offset 'name' on line 113

And i receive one P

And for $_FILES i receive:

Undefined index

Comment: It's `$_FILES` not `$_FILE` please also note to add the right `enctype` to your form so that PHP knows you're sending a file to the server.

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your HTML `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

On your line 113, there should be:

```
$imagem = $_FILES['file']['name']; // not $FILE
```